# MS Word document always opens to last page?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got an MS Word document that always opens to the top of the final page. I know that spreadsheets will open to the last area you viewed before you saved them, but I've never seen a Word document open to anything BUT the top.

I've tried saving it as a Word 2003 .doc, as well as a Word 2007 .docx, and in both cases it opens to the final page. This is bizarre, and it's annoying my boss.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is lame, but whenever I have weird issues with Word documents that I can't figure out, I select the entire document, copy it to the clipboard and paste it into a new blank document.  It's amazing how often that sorts things out.

Comment: +1 This simple if silly technique has saved my bacon many times.

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro to move insertion point to the end of document and the set that macro to run when ever a document is opened or new document is created.

It is easier like this!

Answer (score 0):

Try Shift + F5.
It should work.